# Client interface web service iphone

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, content-management-system

my question is: We are developing a IOS app that requires the users to upload content to it (Photos, Videos, Text), through a website, we are testing several options, but we cannot find a user friendly interface (like a nice open source CMS) to do it. Our server is a PHP one.

The main features we need to have on the CMS interface are:

secure login /user and Password
upload content to the server (videos, images and text), which will be tagged in different categories

Any ideas or other tested solutions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are companies like Parse and StackMob trying to make the server side of iPhone development easier.

Are you looking for a server that implements an API for your app to use?
Are you looking for a full website that lets anyone upload stuff to it?

Comment: A very simple website that lets the "client" login and upload stuff to their application :)